# What are the differences and similarities of Sugar Alcohol and the Alcohol in Alcoholic Drinks?

Tags: alcohol

**Question part 1:** In particular of Sugar Alcohols, I ask about Sorbitol.

I am a 100% strict teetotaler. I do not care if a small dose will not intoxicate me, I am absolutely anti-alcoholic.

Recently I ate a few of some treat, first I checked the ingredients at least four times because I was suspicious.. there was no "regular" Alcohol but there was Soribitol. I really wanted to eat the treat even though from my Web searches I was not totally convinced that Sorbitol is clean.. I caved in and I am regretting it. The treat tasted suspicious.

I really am a serious, strict teetotaler 100%. Please advise me.

---

**Question part 2:** If you were an absolutely dead-strict teetotaler.. would you feel bad about eating something that contains Sorbitol?

Comment: Perhaps your question will be ok on https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/ You may want to specify what Sorbitol is though